# Javascript chamando função sem precisar .click

Tags: javascript

Como eu posso chamar essa função sem precisar criar um botão, por exemplo:

O meu controller manda uma notificação para o html de {{error}} ou {{success}} e ambos estão ocultos e eu quero customizar essa informação antes de ser exibida

```
<div class="content" ng-controller="respostasController">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="error" class="ng-hide">
        <span>{{error}} </span>
            <button class="close" type="button" ng-click="close()">x</button>
    </div>,
    <div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="success" class="ng-hide">
        <span>{{success}} </span>
            <button class="close" type="button" ng-click="close()">x</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Eu quero pegar essa informação {{error}} e {{success}} e customizar ela no script abaixo antes de exibir na página

```
$('#clique').click(function(){

        $.bootstrapGrowl("div 1",{
            allow_dismiss: false,
            type: 'danger'
        });

        $.bootstrapGrowl("div 2",{
            allow_dismiss: false,
            type: 'success'
        });
    });
```

Comment: Se minha div vir 1? Explique melhor o que você quer.

Comment: editei, acho que consegui explicar o que venho tentando fazer

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você está usando angular para renderizar a página. Neste caso, você pode alterar diretamente a variável em `$scope`. A alteração é aplicada diretamente na tela, sem o evento de click. Você ainda pode definir o valor desta variável na inicialização do controller.

**Exemplo**

http://codepen.io/vhkrausser/pen/gwKBxg

Comment: você poderia dá um exemplo?

Comment: @João, adicionei um exemplo. Espero que ajude na sua situação.